# How to validate bootstrap radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to validate this section of the form but whichever button is selected, option1 returns false. How can I get each radio to have different values when they are active/inactive or alternatively get a value from the button-group?

```js
$(function register(){
$('.err').hide();
$("#submit").click(function() { 
if  ($('#option1').prop("checked", false)){
        $("#fcerr").show();
    }
if  ($('#option1').prop("checked")){
    $("#fcerr").hide();
}
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-sm" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label id="lopt1" class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Staff
       </label>
       <label id="lopt2" class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="radio" name="option2" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Client
       </label>
</div>
<div><label class="err" id="fcerr">Error Message</label></div>

<input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="submit">
```

I have also tried getting the values of the radio boxes but they are always "on" regardless of which radio is active.

```js
var client = $("#option2").val();
alert(client);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code:

```
if  ($('#option1').prop("checked", false)){
    $("#fcerr").show();
}
```

You are actually setting the property "checked" to be false, everytime. After that is done the if statement recieves a truthy value so it will execute what's inside the if block.

Try your validation like this instead:

```
if($('#option1').is(':checked')){
    //...
}
```

Also, if you want your inputs to actually behave as a group (meaning only one can be checked at a given time) you have to share the same `name` attribute, you can update your html to:

```
<label id="lopt1" class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="radio" name="myOptions" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Staff
       </label>
       <label id="lopt2" class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="radio" name="myOptions" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Client
       </label>
```

Comment: this is the answer which you looking for

Comment: This does work but if I switch to the other radio mid validation they are both checked

Comment: `if  ($('#option1').prop("checked")){
        alert(2);
    }
    if  ($('#option2').prop("checked")){
        alert(1);
    }`

Comment: you should be using the same "name" property for all your inputs if you actually want to make them behave like a "group", see the updated answer in a sec

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: sure, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You didn't include a javascript framework in your code snippet, though your question is tagged with jQuery.
2. The 4th line `if  ($('#option1').prop("checked", false)){` is changing the value that you're trying to evaluate.
3. The option elements should share the same name attribute if you want to treat them as a group that can be validated

Comment: This pretty much sums it up.  Here's a fiddle for ya: https://jsfiddle.net/jda7br95/